# OFDM vs. SC FDMA

Tags: lte

I am learning LTE, there are something I want to figure out.

Why using single carrier FDMA (SC-FDMA)? and why OFDMA for the downlink?

SC-FDMA is designed for solving high PAPR (Peak to average power ratio). As I know high PAPR wolud caused power consuming, but I don't know why. Another question is about SC-FDMA, I can't realize why using a DFT precoding(?) can become single carrier and solving PAPR problem.
[image]

figure from 3GPP TR 25.814 V7.1.0 (2006-09)

Comment: *As I know high PAPR wolud caused power consuming,* No, that's not correct in itself. To *counter one of the effects of PAPR*, one can build a more power-hungry system, but the direct consequence of high PAPR leading to high power consumption isn't correct. *but I don't know why.* That's fine, but what research in that direction have you already done? What's that you found out? PAPR in OFDM is *really* a broadly discussed topic of the last 25 years, so I know that one can easily find a lot of good resources using e.g. google scholar.

Comment: That means that you probably already read something, but didn't fully understand it – so we don't have to explain all of PAPR again. So, please explain what you've researched so far, so that we can write better answers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PAPR in the SC-FDMA system](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/18237/papr-in-the-sc-fdma-system)